# What are the possible integer values for spanning tree counts of a graph on n vertices?

Tags: co.combinatorics

A. Cayley showed that $n^\left(n-2\right)$ tightly upper bounds the number of spanning trees of a graph on $n$ vertices. Is there a closed form formula for the integer values in the range $[0,n^\left(n-2\right)]$ which correspond to spanning tree counts for some graph on n vertices.

Comment: I trust you are familiar with the matrix-tree theorem, which counts the number of spanning trees, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem (not that this provides an immediate answer to the question).

Comment: What do you mean by "a closed formula for the integer values"?

Comment: I assume the question is asking about whether we can determine (in some sense) the range of possible values taken by the complexities (i.e. spanning tree numbers) of all the graphs on $n$ vertices. I'm sure that this would be impossibly difficult.

Comment: very nice question!